# How to check if another user of me can access on this current page

Tags: php, symfony, security, runas

In my app I want to check if another user of the app can access a specific route.

How to use the security compoment of Symfony to load the target user context and check the right as if the user call the URL ?

EDIT :

I known the documentation of Symfony2. But all oriented for current logged user. But in my case, I'm an admin and I want share the current page with another admin.

Before send the share email, I want check if the another admin can read the shared page.

Comment: I think you should make an effort and take a look to the official documentation! http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/security.html

Comment: How can we know that if we don't know what kind of access restrictions  you applied in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

1) create a token `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken` with user.

2) use the `'security.access.decision_manager'` for decide if the user have the granted access.

This solution is simple but not shared here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) or [Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) to achieve your needs.